# TypeError: '_VirtualList' object is not callable

Tags: python, pdf, reader

when ever i run this code my GUI show this error:

> _VirtualList' object is not callable

where im wrong?

```
import PyPDF2
pdf = open("the-alchemist-paulo-coelho.pdf", "rb")
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf)
page = reader.pages(0)
print(page.extractText())
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `page = reader.pages[0]`
instead of
`page = reader.pages(0)`

Answer (score 1):

I just tested what you want to do accourding to the documentation of the PyPDF2 and it did what you want to achive

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
page = reader.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()

print(text)
```

Does this produce the correct result?