# I am facing this error when using py2pdf for page in range(pdf_reader.pages()): TypeError: '_VirtualList' object is not callable

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to create a python code to embed javascript into a PDF File. The Javascript code should do the following

- Check if a span with an ID of "mac-address" exists.
- If the span does not exist, create a hidden span with an ID of "mac-address" and populate it with the MAC address of the device that opened the PDF file.
- If the span exists, check if its value matches the MAC address of the device that opened the PDF file.
- If the value matches, display an alert.
- If the value does not match, display an alert and erase the PDF file.

This is my code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import PyPDF2
import uuid

# Get MAC address of device
mac_address = hex(uuid.getnode())

# Create JavaScript to be embedded in PDF
js_code = """
var mac_address_span = this.getField("mac-address");
if (mac_address_span == null) {
    var new_span = this.addField("mac-address", "text", 0, [0, 0, 0, 0]);
    new_span.value = "%s";
    new_span.display = display.hidden;
    app.alert("MAC address span created with value: " + new_span.value);
} else {
    if (mac_address_span.value == "%s") {
        app.alert("MAC address span exists with matching value: " + mac_address_span.value);
    } else {
        app.alert("MAC address span exists with non-matching value: " + mac_address_span.value);
        this.closeDoc(true);
    }
}
""" % (mac_address, mac_address)

# Open PDF
with open("example.pdf", mode="rb") as f:
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(f)
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    # Embed JavaScript
    pdf_catalog = pdf_reader.trailer["/Root"]
    #pdf_catalog = pdf_reader.catalog
    pdf_catalog_js = pdf_catalog.get_object()
    pdf_catalog_js.update({
        PyPDF2.generic.NameObject('/Names'): PyPDF2.generic.DictionaryObject({
            PyPDF2.generic.NameObject('/JavaScript'): PyPDF2.generic.DictionaryObject({
                PyPDF2.generic.NameObject('/Names'): PyPDF2.generic.ArrayObject([
                    PyPDF2.generic.TextStringObject('mac-address'),
                    PyPDF2.generic.IndirectObject(len(pdf_writer._objects)+1, 0, pdf_writer)
                ])
            })
        })
    })

    # Add JavaScript action to document open event
    js_name = 'mac-address.js'
    js_action = pdf_writer.add_js(js_code)
    
    if js_action:
        pdf_writer._add_object(js_action)
    else:
        print("Failed to create JavaScript action object")

    pdf_open_action = PyPDF2.generic.DictionaryObject({
        PyPDF2.generic.NameObject('/S'): PyPDF2.generic.NameObject('/JavaScript'),
        PyPDF2.generic.NameObject('/JS'): PyPDF2.generic.NameObject(js_name)
    })


    pdf_catalog_js.update({
        PyPDF2.generic.NameObject('/OpenAction'): pdf_open_action
    })


    pdf_catalog_js.update({
        PyPDF2.generic.NameObject('/OpenAction'): pdf_open_action
    })

    # Add all pages to output PDF
    for page in range(pdf_reader.pages()):
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

    # Save output PDF
    with open("output.pdf", mode="wb") as output_file:
        pdf_writer.write(output_file)

# Open output PDF
if os.name == 'nt':  # for Windows OS
    os.startfile("output.pdf")
else:  # for Mac OS
    subprocess.call(["open", "output.pdf"])
```

I keep getting this error:

for page in range(pdf_reader.pages()):
TypeError: '_VirtualList' object is not callable

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75248715/typeerror-virtuallist-object-is-not-callable - pdf_reader.pages isn't a function.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf